# Neo4jClient Repository?

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, repository-pattern, neo4jclient

Has anyone succeed in developing a repository for Neo4j>2.0 and Neo4jClient? I searched extensively in the internet for a repository pattern but all available are based on Neo4j<2.0.  Since I am new to this, it would help me considerably if someone could share the code.

Comment: I don't believe such thing exists. To be honest, it's actually pretty easy to create such patterns with neo4j which I somehow agree that something like this should exist. I myself have such patterns in a project I am working on maybe at some point to open source it but I am just too lazy :p